# Vue.js Vuex State Change doesn't rerender a template with v-if

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios, vuex

I've tried having the v-if value set in computed, data, passed as props and just a direct reference to state but it NEVER re renders despite the fact that the state I check for is changed to true.

Currently I have it directly referencing the store

```
<template v-if="this.$store.state.showReviews">
```

I perform an AJAX Request in my Vuex Action

```
getBikeReviews(context, i){
  console.log("getBikeReviews");
  axios.get('http://mpaccione.com/wp-content/themes/webdev/projects/Web_Design_4/Creating_Online_Store/api/get_reviews.php?index='+i).then((res) => {
    context.commit('storeBikeReviews', {"index": i, "json": res.data});
    context.commit('showReviews', true);
  });
}
```

The State gets Mutated to true

```
showReviews (state, payload){
  console.log("showReviews");
  state.showReviews = payload;
}
```

However the template never re-renders.

Comment: Is `showReviews` initially declared in your vuex `state`? Vue cannot detect property additions.

Comment: Yes it is initially declared in my state...

const state = {
  bikes: [],
  reviews: [],
  showReviews: false,
  uploadProgress: []
}

Comment: You don't use `this` in template `<template v-if="$store.state.showReviews">`

Comment: I've made the change but I have the same outcome. I checked the store with {{  }} and it returns true but there is no re render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using getters or computed values?

```
computed: {
  showReviews() {
    return this.$store.state.reviews || []
  },
  reviews() {
    return this.$store.state.showReviews === true
  }
}
```

also, it's a good idea to use Vue.$set whenever possible instead of simple assignment.

```
Import Vue from 'vue';

showReviews (state, payload){
  Vue.$set(state, 'showReviews', payload);
}
```

while this may not resolve the issue with some value types, IMHO, it's a good idea to just apply all the time, so you don't forget the one that does need it.

finally, if you're really struggling to get the reactivity to kick in, you can force a re-render by calling `this.$forceUpdate();` *(or `Vue.$forceUpdate();`)* after your mutation

Comment: As a side note, your ajax responds with html format. You should set it to json if you have access to that.

Comment: Thank you this was an excellent answer and led me to understand Vue.js better along with setters and getters: https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407. Using Vue.set was what made this work!